# Finding German birth record for Heinz Gunther Edward Curdt in early 20th Century?

Tags: germany, birth-records, death-records, birthplace

I have been extensively researching my family ancestry. My grandfather is German and moved to England at age 7 around 1950-1952.  I do not believe his father moved to England with him as he never knew his father.

I am trying to find out anything about my great grandfather, Heinz Gunther Eduard Curdt. On Ancestry there is only one record where he lived (Hameln 1950).  I can't find any birth or marriage record to "Marx" and I am hoping anyone can find anything on him. My grandfather is ill and I would like to find some answers for him.

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! You are more likely to get good answers if you ask a specific research question. "Anything" questions are too broad.  You can learn more about how the site works by taking the [tour] and reading our [help], especially https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I can not see any reference to "Marx" in your question, other than you saying you can't find vital records for that name.  Where does this come from?

Comment: Since your grandfather is alive, our Privacy Policy (see our [help/on-topic]) prevents using his name here. His father may have been born less than 100 years ago which would also be problematic but I think we should assume he was born just over 100 years ago and leave his name in.